# Users tell me that IE9 behavior changes with developer toolbar

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

Some of my users reported that our website behavior changes if they show or hide the developer toolbar on IE9. Since they are not very technical, I don't have much data to debug on, so I can't really be more precise.

I correctly handle the `console.log` function (executing it only if there's the developer toolbar).

What else could lead to such a behavior?

Comment: You're right, this doesn't belong on Programmers. The topic belongs on SO, but you'll need to add a lot more detail in order for it to survive there.

Comment: @cpa: Step 1: Find a machine with IE9, or [Make an IE9 VM](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575) .  Step 2: Reproduce the issue. Step 3: Use binary search for bug.